# n vs. N in notation (proof writing)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

I am currently taking a real analysis course where we are proving limits. A theorem we are using, precise definition of a limit at infinity, states that if $\varepsilon > 0$ then there exists an $N$ s.t. that $n>N$ implies $|s_n - s| < \varepsilon.$ We use this theorem quite often, however the notation "$n > N$" confuses me. As we've moved on to more difficult proofs "$n > N$" has been occuring more and more. For example, proving

$$\liminf \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right| < \liminf|s_n|^{1/n} < \limsup |s_n|^{1/n} < \limsup \left|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\right|$$

Eventually the proof shows $n - N$ fractions exists in $|s_n|.$ However, the meaning of this is lost on me. I always thought $n$ was just some number in the set and $N$ represented the whole set. If that is so then how can $n > N$? I've tried finding the interpretation online and in the book but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: The notation is meant to capture the notion of "for all sufficiently large $n$". The idea is that $N$ determines what "sufficiently large" means (so, any $n>N$ is sufficiently large).

Comment: Here $N$ represents a big enough integer and $n$ represents each integer bigger than $N$.  Personally, I often write $N_0$ for the former and $N$ for the latter, but they each still represent particular integers

Comment: Alternatively, what the statement is saying is that the set $\{n\mid |s_n-s|\geq\epsilon\}$ is finite for any $\epsilon>0.$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I always thought [...] $N$ represented the whole set"*: no. $\mathbb{N}$ is standard notation the set of natural integers. $N$ is not; $N$ is commonly used for *some* integer, the same way $n$ is used (and, quite often, other letters like $m,k,M,K$...).

Comment: I wonder if whoever came up with this notation may have thought "ok, I want some *big* N such that when my number is bigger than that... so let me write a really big *letter* N..."

Comment: @Clement C. Yes I understand that, but what are the implications of n > N? e.g. |sn| = |sn/sn-1| ... |sN+1/sN| . |sN| I understand the terms cancel out and we are left with |sn| but what is the expansion of this sequence demonstrating?

Comment: Think of it as "There exists some big number (this is $N$; it can depend on things like $\varepsilon$) such that all numbers after it (the $n$'s) satisfy...".This tries to capture the notion of "for all integers $n$ *big enough*..."

Comment: @ClementC. Ah ok I see now. Thank you.

Comment: @DPek You're welcome!